# `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but only modify the first child

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

**A Brief Background**

I'm making a conventional forum to learn/practice Rails.

```
User Model
  has_many :topics
  has_many :posts

Topic Model
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user

Post Model
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
```

However, when a User is creating a new Topic, I also want them to simultaneously create the first Post within that topic (just like forums work). Additionally, when the Topic creator edits the Topic, he also edits the first Post.

So, I added `accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts` to the Topic model.

```
# TopicController
def new
  @topic = current_user.topics.new
  @topic.posts.build
end
```

And here's the nested form:

```
# topics/_form
<%= form_for [@topic] do |topic| %>
  <%= topic.text_field :name %>
  <% topic.fields_for :posts do |post| %>
    <%= post.text_area :content %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**The Question**

This code works. The User will create a first Post alongside the creation of a Topic.

However, as other Users create Posts for the Topic and `@topic.posts` expands, when the Topic creator edits the Topic, text areas for every post in the Topic appear as editable by the Topic creator.

**How can I make it so the Topic creator can only see and edit the first post of the Topic on the `views/topics/_form` form??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helpful resource: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Created a new partial alongside `topics/_form` called `_edit_form` just for the `topics#edit` action.

Reading the API doc (go figure), I found that you can specify an instance for `forms_for`:

```
<%= form_for @topic do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.fields_for :posts, ---->@post<---- do |p| %>
        <%= p.text_area :content %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

In the Topics Controller:

```
def edit
  @topic = ...
  @post = @topic.posts.first
end
```