# How to remove, "Remove" link if form field is the first form field on the page with Nested_Form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-form-for

I am using the nested_form gem that allows the user to add and remove form fields dynamically. It is working fine, but I would like to be able to prevent the user from removing the first file_field, and only show the "Remove" link if it is a field that the user had added. My '_form' and '_photo_fields' partials are below. I think the solution would be to do something like, "if this field is not the first field of its type on the page, then, show the 'Remove' link," but I am not sure how to accomplish that. Thank you for any insight you can provide.

**_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @service_offering do |f|%>

... Other Fields ...

<%= f.fields_for :photos do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'photo_fields', :f => builder %>
<%end%>

<%= f.button :submit %>

<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add Photo", :photos %></p>
```

**_photo_fields.html.erb:**

```
<% if f.object.new_record? %>

<%= f.label :photo %>  
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
# This is where I want to drop that if statement, but I am not sure what it should be.
<%= f.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
#
<%end%>

<% unless f.object.new_record? %>

<%= link_to( image_tag(f.object.photo.url(:thumb))) %>
<%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
<%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove" %>

<%end%>
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot hide it from ERB in view, beacause what is rendered inside the fields_for block is then used as template for the "add new" button. So if you hide remove link there, no one added item will have remove link.

As I looked on the nested_form_for code, it has no native support for this. Simplest solution, but not ideal, is to hide remove link on the client by CSS or JS.

I solved it with this JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[data-nested-form-disable-first]').each(function() {
    var nested_container = $(this).closest('.fields');

    // check if is first
    if (!nested_container.prev().is('.fields')) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

And then add 'data-nested-form-disable-first' to remove link definition:

```
<%= f.link_to_remove 'Remove', 'data-nested-form-disable-first' => '' %>
```

It works only when you have ensured that the not-removable field is in the page when it is loaded.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot! Wonderful solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see here two options for you:

1. If your photo could be asked if it can be removed, that would be the easiest solution
2. You could try to hide the link in the form by CSS.

#### Photo API

Try to expand your photo model by a method like

```
class Photo ...
  def removable?
    ...
  end
end
```

**_photo_fields.html.erb:**

```
...
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
<% if f.object.photo.removable? %>
  <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
<% end %>
```

#### Using CSS

I'm not sure, but it should be possible by:

1. Add a `div` for your photo field
2. Add to your CSS the relevant rules.

So here is the code (only the fragments you should change or add:

**_photo_fields.html.erb:**

```
<div class="photo_fields">
   ...
   <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove", :class => "remove" %>
   ...
</div>
```

**application.css:**

```
div.photo_field:first-child > a.remove {
  display: none;
}
```

The first solution is the right one, if possible, because it does not allow at all to remove the non-removable thing. The second one is a workaround that hides the link, but is much weaker.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The CSS approch makes sense, but I am still fairly new to rails and I am having a hard time trying to figure out what that "removable?" method might be. Could you provide any assistance as to what that may be? I found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972287/accepts-nested-attributes-for-but-only-modify-the-first-child) that talked about specifying an instance for "form_for" I am not sure if that would help? Also, do you know of any good resources for learning to write methods? I could not seem to find any in my Googling. Thank you!